# how to use two intents within one button click?

Tags: android, email

I am trying to send an email when clicking on a `Button`, and I want to go to the homepage of app that after sending the email. I tried this code but it is not working. I am able to send the email but after that I can't go to the homepage, I am coming to the same page from where I send the email.

```
public void onSendClick(View view) {
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
    intent.setType("Audio/mp3");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Attachment from app");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Sending mp3 file ");

    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"email@example.com"});
    ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();

    uris.add(Uri.fromFile(new File(mFileName.getAbsolutePath())));

    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send mail"));

  /* Intent i = new Intent(SubmitActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    //i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    this.startActivity(i); */
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using startActivityForResult method and navigate to homepage in onActivityResult callback. onActivtyResult callback is invoked after Email activity is destroyed.

```
    static final int EMAIL_REQUEST = 1;

    public void onSendClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
        intent.setType("Audio/mp3");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Attachment from app");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Sending mp3 file ");

        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"xxx@yahoo.co.uk"});
        ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();

        uris.add(Uri.fromFile(new File(mFileName.getAbsolutePath())));

        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send mail"), EMAIL_REQUEST);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == EMAIL_REQUEST) {
            //Navigate to home page from here.
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks a lot, actually I was not doing properly, now it's works, Thanks a lot...:-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are in an activity invoked from the homepage activity, try

```
startActivity(..);
finish();
```